# How do I call a method repeatedly without blocking the UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, nonblocking

Pretty generic question, is there a way to call a method I have every so often with the application without blocking the UI load?

Comment: Call it on background thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, kNilOptions), ^{
    // Call your method.
});
```

Comment: Will this recursively call it though?

Comment: I see now that you had tagged the question 'recursion'. No, this simply executes whatever code you put in the block on a background thread. You can certainly use GCD in tandem with recursion or iteration. GCD's purpose is to improve concurrent code execution.

Comment: For those finding this question, be sure to check out the answer from 0x7fffffff regarding dispatch_apply.

Answer (score 5):

You definitely want to use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to do this, but I'd just like to point out that GCD has a method build just for this kind of thing. `dispatch_apply()` executes its block a specified number of times on a queue of your choosing, of course, tracking which iteration you're on along the way. Here's an example:

```
size_t iterations = 10;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_apply(iterations, queue, ^(size_t i) {
    NSLog(@"%zu",i);// Off the main thread.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Go back to main queue for UI updates and such
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(aMethod) withObject:nil];
```

for a method with no parameters. Or something like

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(otherMethodWithString:andData:) withObjects:string, data, nil];
```

if you have parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example, explaining how to execute background queues and iterate with the user inside it.

```
- (void)method
{
    // start a background proccess that will not block the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

            if (i == 999) {

                // Need to iterate with interface elements when inside a background thread.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Found" message:@"Found your number" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertView show];
                });
            }

            NSLog(@"Count: %d",i);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You want `i < 1000000`, not `i > 1000000`.

Comment: It only shows one alert, when it finds the number 999.

Comment: @alexandresoli Oh duh, sorry. Skipped that somehow :p

Answer (score 1):

Using GCD is definitely a good way to go, as others have noted.

Alternatively, if you want the operation to be cancelable (e.g. loading a web resource), you might consider subclassing `NSOperation` and checking for `isCancelled`.

([AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) actually does this (e.g. `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`) in making / managing web requests.)

Checkout the Apple docs on `NSOperation` and also [this tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) for more details on `NSOperation`s.